# How to test a function inside componentwillunmount in react using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test for containers in react using jest and enzyme. My react code is like this:

AgentForm.js

```
import {
        resetStatusMessage,
        formSetError,
        formResetError,
        createAgent,
        updateAgent
        } from "../../actions";    

componentWillMount = () => {
const {
  agents,
  match,
  push,
  resetStatusMessage,
  formResetError
  } = this.props;
    this.edit = false;
    this.isNewAvatar = false;
    this.agent = {};
    if (match.params.id) {
      this.edit = true;
      this.agent = getAgent(agents, match.params.id);
      if ("undefined" === typeof this.agent) {
       push("/agents");
      }
  }
  resetStatusMessage();
  formResetError();
 };
```

And my test code is like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../../store/configureStore";
import AgentForm from "./index";
import { mount } from "enzyme";

 it("should call resetStatusMessage when mounted", () => {
 let mockResetStatusMessage = jest.fn(),
 store = configureStore();
 const wrapper = mount(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <AgentForm resetStatusMessage={mockResetStatusMessage} />
 </Provider>
 );
 expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
 expect(mockResetStatusMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

But the test fail with an error message:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected mock function to have been called
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 4):

you are shallow rendering your component which means it does not have access to the mounting and unmounting lifecycle. use mount wrapper instead of the shallow wrapper

Comment: i use mount instead of shallow. but it shows some other error Like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined. Actually my componentWill mount contain some more functionalities. i update the above code.

Comment: you need to pass mocked "match" as prop to your component from test.